# Finding a marker by option value

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Let's say that you have a Leaflet map, with a set of custom markers, and each marker has a unique id value:

```
var marker = new L.marker(latlong, {id: id, icon: icon}).addTo(map);
```

What's the recommended way to access a marker (specifically, I'd like to modify a marker's class), by its 'id' value?

Comment: note: you can/should (perhaps this was amended in most recent versions of Leaflet) use "uniqueID" instead

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Iterate all the map's layer, check if it's a marker and compare the id's:

```
L.Map.include({
    getMarkerById: function (id) {
        var marker = null;
        this.eachLayer(function (layer) {
            if (layer instanceof L.Marker) {
                if (layer.options.id === id) {
                    marker = layer;
                }
            }
        });
        return marker;
    }
});

var map = new L.Map(...);

var marker = new L.Marker(..., {id: 1});

map.getMarkerById(1); // returns marker instance
map.getMarkerById(2); // returns null
```

Comment: if (layer.options.uniqueID === id)   worked for me instead

Answer (score 3):

Instead of looping through all markers, I'd suggest keeping a [dictionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array) of markers, using their ID as the key, e.g.:

```
var markers = {};

markers[id] = new L.marker(latlong, {id: id, icon: icon}).addTo(map);
```

Then you simply refer to `marker[id]`.

A more complicated example:

```
var markers = {};
var data = [ ['alpha', 0, -80],
             ['beta',  20, 35],
             ['delta', -70, 44],
           ];

data.forEach(function(item){
    var id = item[0];
    var latLng = L.latLng(item[1], item[2]);
    markers[id] = new L.marker(latLng, {id: id, icon: icon}).addTo(map);
});

console.log(markers['delta']); // returns the marker at -70, 44
```

Comment: I think keeping another dict is BS. Work with what you've already got. But i catch your drift. Kinda depends on the usecase tho.

Comment: Sure, we don't know the architecture of OP's program. But I don't think this is *another* dict, is the only dict here.